# Cómo actualizar una tabla con ajax y datatable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

Muy buenas noches , estoy haciendo un crud con datables , php y mysql , el inconveniente que tengo es que al utilizar ajax para hacer un reload , aparece el error "DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/1"](http://datatables.net/tn/1%22) , entiendo que se debe a que durante ese lapso de tiempo Json regresa vacío , ya que después de unos segundo si doy f5 hace la llamada correctamente , quisiera poder hacer el reload cuando la tabla ya este llena pero no consigo hacerlo , cabe decir que en mi localhost no tengo ese problema , solo se da en el hosting . Tambien ví que aparece el error "El error de Conexion es: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)" durante el tiempo en el que aparece el error de Datatables .Espero me puedan dar una mano , muchas gracias

Codigo ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var user_id, opcion;
  opcion = 4;
      
  tablaUsuarios = $('#dataTable').DataTable({  
      "ajax":{            
          "url": "bd/crud.php", 
          "method": 'POST', //usamos el metodo POST
          "data":{opcion:opcion}, //enviamos opcion 4 para que haga un SELECT
          "dataSrc":""
      },
      "columns":[
          {"data": "id"},         
          {"data": "id_usuario"},
          {"data": "nombres"},
          {"data": "apellidos"},
          {"data": "fec_inicio_prueba"},
          {"data": "fec_fin_prueba"},
          {"data": "turno"},
          {"data": "perfil"},
          {"data": "dni"},
          {"data": "carrera"},
          {"data": "telefono"},
          {"data": "link_cv"},
          {"data": "correo"},
          {"data": "condicion_capacitacion"},
          {"data": "link_calificaciones"},
          {"data": "convenio"},
          {"data": "link_convenio"},
          {"data": "fecha_nac"},
          {"data": "unidad_asig"},
          {"data": "fecha_in_pr"},
          {"data": "dias_extra"},
          {"data": "fecha_salida_pr"},
          {"data": "fecha_fn_pr"},
          {"data": "dias_fin_pr"},
          {"data": "nro_dias_cumple"},
          {"data": "condicion_practicas"},
          {"data": "estado"},
          {"data": "tipo_emp"}, 
          {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button></div></div>"}
      ],
      "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
          "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
          "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
          "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
          "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
          "sSearch": "Buscar:",
          "oPaginate": {
              "sFirst": "Primero",
              "sLast":"Último",
              "sNext":"Siguiente",
              "sPrevious": "Anterior"
          },
          "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
      }
  });
  
  var fila; //captura la fila, para editar o eliminar

  //submit para el Alta y Actualización
  $('#formUsuarios').submit(function(e){                         
      e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
      nombres = $.trim($('#nombres').val()); 
      apellidos = $.trim($('#apellidos').val()); 
      fecha_in_pr = $.trim($('#fecha_in_pr').val()); 
      fecha_fn_pr = $.trim($('#fecha_fn_pr').val()); 
      turno = $.trim($('#turno').val()); 
      perfil =$('#perfil').val(); 
      dni = $.trim($('#dni').val()); 
      telefono = $.trim($('#telefono').val()); 
      link_cv = $.trim($('#link_cv').val()); 
      correo = $.trim($('#correo').val());   
      condicion_capa = $('#condicion_capa').val(); 
      link_calificacion = $.trim($('#link_calificacion').val()); 
      convenio =  $('#convenio').val(); 
      link_convenio=$.trim($('#link_convenio').val()); 
      fecha_nac = $.trim($('#fecha_nac').val()); 
      unidad = $('#unidad').val(); 
      carrera = $.trim($('#carrera').val()); 
      estado = $.trim($('#estado').val()); 
      dias_extra = $.trim($('#dias_extra').val()); 
      $("#carga").show();       
          $.ajax({
            url: "bd/crud.php",
            type: "POST",
            datatype:"json",    
            data:  {user_id:user_id,nombres:nombres, apellidos:apellidos, fecha_in_pr:fecha_in_pr, fecha_fn_pr:fecha_fn_pr, 
            turno:turno, perfil:perfil ,dni:dni ,telefono:telefono,link_cv:link_cv,correo:correo,condicion_capa:condicion_capa,
            link_calificacion:link_calificacion,convenio:convenio,link_convenio:link_convenio,fecha_nac:fecha_nac,unidad:unidad,
            carrera:carrera,estado:estado,dias_extra,opcion:opcion} ,
           
                success: function(data) {  
                              
                    tablaUsuarios.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    $('#modalCRUD').modal('hide');   
                    /*setInterval( function () {
                        tablaUsuarios.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
                    }, 30000 );*/
                    //$('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null,false);
               }

          });   
                                                            
  });
          
   
  
  //para limpiar los campos antes de dar de Alta una Persona
  $("#btnNuevo").click(function(){
      opcion = 1; //alta           
      user_id=null;
      $("#formUsuarios").trigger("reset");
      $(".modal-header").css( "background-color", "#FFC300");
      $(".modal-header").css( "color", "white" );
      $(".modal-title").text("Alta de Empleado");
      $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
      $('#div_estado').hide();
      $('#div_dias').hide();
      $('#carga').hide();           
  });
  //if(fila.find('td:eq(6)').text()=="1"){ turno = "Mañana"};  //
  //Editar        
  $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){             
      opcion = 2;//editar
      fila = $(this).closest("tr");         
      user_id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text()); //capturo el ID                 
      nombres = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
      apellidos = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
      fecha_in_pr = fila.find('td:eq(4)').text();
      fecha_fn_pr = fila.find('td:eq(5)').text();
      turno = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();
      perfil = fila.find('td:eq(7)').text();
      dni = fila.find('td:eq(8)').text();
      telefono = fila.find('td:eq(10)').text(); 
      link_cv = fila.find('td:eq(11)').text();
      correo = fila.find('td:eq(12)').text();  
      condicion_capa = fila.find('td:eq(13)').text();  
      link_calificacion = fila.find('td:eq(14)').text(); 
      convenio =  fila.find('td:eq(15)').text(); 
      link_convenio=fila.find('td:eq(16)').text(); 
      fecha_nac = fila.find('td:eq(17)').text();
      unidad = fila.find('td:eq(18)').text();
      estado = fila.find('td:eq(26)').text();
      dias_extra = fila.find('td:eq(20)').text();
      carrera = fila.find('td:eq(9)').text();

      $("#nombres").val(nombres);
      $("#apellidos").val(apellidos);
      $("#fecha_in_pr").val(fecha_in_pr);
      $("#fecha_fn_pr").val(fecha_fn_pr);
      $("#turno").val(turno);
      $("#perfil").val(perfil);
      $("#dni").val(dni);
      $("#telefono").val(telefono);
      $("#link_cv").val(link_cv);
      $("#correo").val(correo);
      $("#condicion_capa").val(condicion_capa);
      $("#link_calificacion").val(link_calificacion);
      $("#convenio").val(convenio);
      $("#link_convenio").val(link_convenio);
      $("#fecha_nac").val(fecha_nac);
      $("#unidad").val(unidad);
      $("#estado").val(estado);
      $("#dias_extra").val(dias_extra);
      $("#carrera").val(carrera);

      $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#FFC300");
      $(".modal-header").css("color", "white" );
      $(".modal-title").text("Editar Usuario");     
      $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
      $('#div_estado').show();  
      $('#div_dias').show();    
      $('#carga').hide();   
  });
  
  //Borrar
  $(document).on("click", ".btnBorrar", function(){
      fila = $(this);           
      user_id = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()) ;       
      opcion = 3; //eliminar        
      var respuesta = confirm("¿Está seguro de borrar el registro "+user_id+"?");                
      if (respuesta) {            
          $.ajax({
            url: "bd/crud.php",
            type: "POST",
            datatype:"json",    
            data:  {opcion:opcion, user_id:user_id},    
            success: function() {
                tablaUsuarios.row(fila.parents('tr')).remove().draw(); 
                tablaUsuarios.ajax.reload(null, false);                 
             }
          });   
      }
   });

   // validacion de campos
/*
   $('#formUsuariosS').bootstrapValidator({            
    fields: {
       nombres: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'El nombre es obligatorio'
                }
            }
        },
        edad: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'La edad es obligatoria'
                },
                integer: {
                message: 'Debe introducir un valor entero'
            }
            }
        },
        direccion: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'La dirección es obligatoria'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    });
*/


    $('#formUsuarios2')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            nombres: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    /*remote: {
                        url: 'remote.php',
                        message: 'The username is not available'
                    },*/
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    



       
  });
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda , tengo varios días intentando hacer que funcione

Comment: Pienso que es problema de MySQL, son muchos registros?

Comment: Hola ... siii , estaba viendo un ejemplo con 500 registros apox y si funciona bien , no se si el problema será la cantidad de columnas , que son mas de 20

Comment: no puedes pasarle mas columnas de la que debe tener... y debes validar que el JSON devuelto es un JSON correcto...

Comment: El problema es que si hace el crud correctamente , pero se demora unos 10 segundos , y en ese tiempo sale la alerta del json , porque regresa vacío , no se como controlar eso

Comment: Amigos , para quien le ayude .. Lo que hice para solucionar el problema fue hacer el select completo , no con * , sino llamar a cada campo ya que tenia mas de 20 , con eso se solucionó , muchas gracias por su ayuda